# Calculating the average of all nodes in a Binary Search Tree using visitors

Tags: java, tree, binary-search, visitor-pattern

I'm required to calculate the average value of all nodes in a BST using a `Visitor`, I'm not sure if I did this correctly or if i could just calculate the average with `inOrder()` and therefore I'm not really utilizing the visitor.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Node{

    int val;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    private static int sum;
    private static int count;
    private static double average;

    public Node(int val){
        this.val = val;
    }

    public int getVal(){
        return val;
    }

    public interface Visitor {
        int visit(Node node);
    }

    static class NodeVisitorImpl implements Visitor{
        @Override
        public int visit(Node node) {
            return node.getVal();
        }
    }


    public void insert(int toInsert) {
        if (toInsert < this.val) {
            if (this.left == null) {
                this.left = new Node(toInsert);
            } else {
                this.left.insert(toInsert);
            }
        } else if (toInsert > this.val) {
            if (this.right == null) {
                this.right = new Node(toInsert);
            } else {
                this.right.insert(toInsert);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Shouldn't have the same value");
        }

    }

    public static void inOrder(Node root){
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }
        Visitor visitor = new NodeVisitorImpl();
        sum += visitor.visit(root);
        count++;
        average = sum/count;
        inOrder(root.left);
        inOrder(root.right);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Node root = new Node(4);
        root.insert(2);
        root.insert(1);
        root.insert(3);
        root.insert(6);
        root.insert(5);
        root.insert(7);

        inOrder(root);
        System.out.println(average);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are doing it somewhat right, somewhat wrong.

Your visitor is more of a Mapping transformer: it is converting `Node` into an `int`.  How it gets that `int` value from the `Node` is left up to the implementation.

Unfortunately, all of your `average` calculation is still inside `inOrder()`.  Worse, your `sum`, `count` and `average` values are `static` members of `Node`, so you cannot do two parallel average calculations.  There is no resetting of the `sum` or `count` so a subsequent average calculation is going to compute the average of the aggregate of all data, not just the most recent tree.

Your `Visitor` `visit()` method should return nothing:

```
public interface Visitor {
    void visit(Node node);
}
```

Then, you can create an `AveragingVisitor` which averages the data it extracts from `Node` objects:

```
static class AveragingVisitor implements Visitor {
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void visit(Node node) {
        sum += node.getVal();
        count++;
    }

    public double average() {
        return (double) sum / count;
    }
}
```

Each time you create a new `AveragingVisitor`, it will start new count & running total at zero.

To compute the average, you would create this averaging visitor, and perform some kind of traversal (inOrder is fine) of the tree:

```
AveragingVisitor visitor = new AveragingVisitor();

root.inOrder(visitor);

System.out.println(visitor.average());
```

Of course, `Node::inOrder(Visitor vistor)` will need to be rewritten as non-static, and call the `visitor.visit(node)` method on each node:

```
public void inOrder(Visitor visitor) {
    if (left != null)
        left.inOrder(visitor);
    visitor.visit(this);
    if (right != null)
        right.inOrder(visitor);
}
```

With this visitor, you could easily make a `PrintingVisitor` to print all of the nodes.  No change would need to be made to `inOrder()`.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense to me up until the inOrder method. It calls for a Visitor but then inside the method you have it going into the left and right nodes. I tried public void inOrder(Node n, Visitor visitor){ inOrder(this.left, visitor); visitor.visit(this); inOrder.visit(this.right, visitor); } but it resulted in a StackOverflowError

Comment: Sorry, corrected the code; previous code wouldn’t have compiled.